# GGTS 3.6.2 and Grails 2.4.4 Run-App and Test-App will not work

Tags: eclipse, grails, ggts

I have recently been trying to upgrade some our projects from Grails 2.2.1 to 2.4.3/4.  Using the command line, I am able to execute a run-app/test-app and everything works fine.

My issue is when I attempt to do either a Run-App or a Test-App inside of GGTS, the process starts up, but immediately terminates with the stack trace below in the eclipse logs.  If I attempt to do the same thing with a 2.2.1 grails version, it works fine.

```
!ENTRY org.grails.ide.eclipse.core 4 0 2014-10-28 15:52:05.158
!MESSAGE Internal Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.workspace.GrailsProject.getServerPort(GrailsProject.java:139)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.launch.GrailsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.addKillPortArg(GrailsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:333)
    at org.grails.ide.eclipse.core.launch.GrailsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(GrailsLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: You'll probably be better off raising an issue in the STS/GGTS JIRA - this seems like a bug, and not the sort of thing the hivemind would be able to come together to help you fix: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.
On all the related projects:

- `grails clean-all`
- right click on the project Grails Tools -> Refresh Dependencies
- `grails maven-install` (only if applies)

After all done you should be able to run: `grails run-app` on your project.
In my case it was a stale project and I updated GGTS in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Make sure that application.properties has the new Grails version
4. Run "grails clean"
5. Run "grails upgrade", option 3
6. "grails run-app" worked.

I thought I had upgraded things fully, but either I hadn't (I was interrupted part way through the process), or maybe Eclipse just needed to be restarted.